# Compare each pandas row to a dictionary of list and append new variable to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to check each row of a pandas dataframe string column and append a new column that returns 1 if any element of the text column is found in a dictionary of list.

Example:

```
# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'text': ['This sentence may contain reference.',
                'Orange, blue cow','Does the cow operate any heavy machinery?']},
                 columns=['numbers', 'text'])

# Rule dictionary
rule_dict = {'rule1': ['Does', 'the'],
             'rule2':['Sentence','contain'],
             'rule3': ['any', 'reference', 'words']}

# List of variable names to be appended to df
rule_list = ['has_rule1','has_rule2','has_rule3']

# Current for loop
for Key in rule_dict:
    for i in rule_list:
        df[i] = df.text.apply(lambda x: (
            1 if any(ele in x for ele in rule_dict[Key]) == 1 and (len(str(x)) >= 3) 
            else 0))

# Current output, looks to be returning a 1 if text is found in ANY of the lists
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                       'text': ['This sentence may contain reference.',
                    'Orange, blue cow','Does the cow operate any heavy machinery?'],
                    'has_rule1': [1,1,1],
                    'has_rule2': [0,0,0],
                    'has_rule3': [1,1,1]},
                     columns=['id', 'text','has_rule1','has_rule2','has_rule3'])

# Anticipated output
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                       'text': ['This sentence may contain reference.',
                    'Orange, blue cow','Does the cow operate any heavy machinery?'],
                    'has_rule1': [0,0,1],
                    'has_rule2': [1,0,0],
                    'has_rule3': [1,0,1]},
                     columns=['id', 'text','has_rule1','has_rule2','has_rule3'])
```

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee in ordering of `rule_dict` when you do `for Key in rule_dict`. That is, you wouldn't know `Key` will come in order of `'rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3'` or `'rule2', 'rule3', 'rule1'` or the like.

Comment: @QuangHoang I did not know that, thank you. I had assumed it would be index based. How can I ensure it maintains the order I specify (i.e., 'rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3')?

Comment: One way is to have `rule_list` also as a dictionary: `{'rule1': 'has_rule1', }` and access both by keys. Another way is to use [OrderedDict](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ordereddict-in-python). But that also depends on your rules' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you sorted out the issue regarding dict comprehension mentioned in the comment, you should not use nested `for` loop. Instead, use a single `for` loop with `zip`:

```
for (k,v), n in zip(rule_dict.items(), rule_list):
    pat = rf'\b{"|".join(v)}\b'
    df[n] = df.text.str.contains(pat).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
      id  text                                         has_rule1    has_rule2    has_rule3
--  ----  -----------------------------------------  -----------  -----------  -----------
 0     1  This sentence may contain reference.                 0            1            1
 1     2  Orange, blue cow                                     0            0            0
 2     3  Does the cow operate any heavy machinery?            1            0            1
```